# PHP function or how to use this code many times in different instances on one page, not using php include

Tags: php, function, loops, foreach

So I want to include this code many times on one page with different data:

```
if (!empty($faq[$fisf][$title]) ) {
    echo '<div class="card card-body col-12"><h5 class="card-title">'.$faq[$fisf][$title].'</h5>';

    if (!empty($faq[$fisf][$image]) ) {
        echo '<img src="'.$faq[$fisf][$image].'" alt="'.$faq[$fisf][$title].'" class="img-fluid">';
    }

    if (!empty($faq[$fisf][$title]) ) {
        echo $faq[$fisf][$text];
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

What I normally do is put this code in a separate file and then include it as many times as I need it and depending on where that code is in a loop or foreach it will show the relevant data!.

But I'm trying to figure out a better way of doing it, like using a function!

Kind of like this:

```
function faqmodal() {
    if (!empty($faq[$fisf][$title])) {
        echo '<div class="card card-body col-12"><h5 class="card-title">'.$faq[$fisf][$title].'</h5>';

        if (!empty($faq[$fisf][$image])) {
            echo '<img src="'.$faq[$fisf][$image].'" alt="'.$faq[$fisf][$title].'" class="img-fluid">';
        }

        if (!empty($faq[$fisf][$title])) {
            echo $faq[$fisf][$text];
        }

        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

I want this function to run within different foreach's and loading the relevant data to where its run.

```
faqmodal();
```

So this part will depend on what the foreach telling it to load it with :

```
$faq[$fisf][$title]
```

But now the function does not convert the code above to be relevant whats in the foreach loop is telling it to fill it with!

But this might not be the smartest way of doing it, I'm open for any ideas!

Comment: Make `$faq` as global veriable. then you can access it into function.

Comment: $faq is a array with the data!

Comment: I hope `$faq` is already initialize outside the function. so you need to use `global` keyword for it to access it inside function.

Comment: Can you show an example of how the implementation will look like? How'd you wanted to use it within a `foreach` loop, cause `$faq[$fisf]` would `$faq` be the array with the items and `$fisf` given the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood correctly, this should be solvable by passing the data as an argument of the function like this:

```
function faqmodal($title, $image, $text){
    if (!empty($title) && !empty($image) && if (!empty($text)) {
        echo '
        <div class="card card-body col-12">
            <h5 class="card-title">'.$title.'</h5>
            <img src="'.$image.'" alt="'.$title.'" class="img-fluid">
        '.$text.'</div>'; //you might wanna think about moving the text into e.g. a <span> tag
    }
}
```

If you now want to call the function you'll do it like so:

```
faqmodal($faq[$fisf][$title], $faq[$fisf][$image], $faq[$fisf][$title]);
```

And the data you pass will vary according to the data you get via the foreach loop. If this isn't what you mean, please let me know via a comment and we'll work our way through this.

Comment: OMG, your a GOD!.. love it.. it works like a charm(ish) your code is kind of messy and many double )) and missing ones.. but other then that.. THAT DID IT! ok i will look in how to make many check if not empty also.. one thing at the time.. im trying to get better!..

Comment: Actually it did not work.. but now when i get the basic of how to use the function i think i can figure it out with little bit of time..

Comment: @user1296114 We can look into it together if you want. Just add a little information and we might be able to get this working. I actually kept the code somewhat messy as that was the way you provided it before the edit of your question. I am going to edit it so it looks better

Comment: @user1296114 just finished the edit, also forgot two "!empty"s in the function call. Maybe it works now...?

Comment: I dont know how to send you a personal message as your site is down. And is Sunday here in Bali, so im a bit drunk and watching the UFC and working on my own stuff all at the same time :)

Comment: @user1296114 Like I said: Maybe a little more information would help... Perhaps you should hit me up tomorrow again with clear instructions. I don't know how I can do more...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185316/discussion-between-user1296114-and-moritz).